# mysql zipcode lat/long radius searches using point

Tags: mysql

does anybody have a MySQL query where I can return all the zipcodes in 150 mile radius from a specific zipcode?  The kicker is my DB uses points and the format as text is (lat lng).  Any hints would be great! Thanks.

Country: USA

City (varchar 25)
State (varchar 10)
Zip (int)
Location (point)
example:location (70 -12)

Comment: You should probably add which country you're talking about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search yielded this [basic MySQL function for caclulating distance between two Geo-points](http://www.posteet.com/view/1555).  To get miles instead of Km, you'd just replace the `6378.388` constant with `3963.1` as described in this [formula breakdown](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~cvm/latlon_formula.html).

Comment: see thats the problem i've been having, all the formula's require a lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2,  the problem is i have one column points with both lats/lons

Comment: Can you maybe post the structure of your data?

Comment: @Mike, you should probably split it out into two columns.